# need help rotating a jpg image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, image-rotation

Can anyone help me figure out how to make my JButton (jbt1) rotate my image which is a jpg file (wheelof.jpg) for a set amount of time? I have been trying to figure this out for a while and no luck looking for any suggestions. Thanks

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

 import javax.swing.*;



 public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ 

     private JButton jbt1 = new JButton("SPIN!");
     private ImageIcon image;
     private JLabel label1;
     private GraphicsPanel canvas = new GraphicsPanel();

     public Game(){
         JPanel control = new JPanel();
         control.setLayout(new FlowLayout(2,2,2));
         control.add(jbt1);
         ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("wheelof.jpg");
         label1 = new JLabel(image);
         control.add(label1);
         add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(control, BorderLayout.EAST);
         jbt1.addActionListener(new RotateListener());
     }//game()

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame gui = new Game();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(800,1000);
        gui.setTitle("Wheel of Fortune");       
    }//main()


    class RotateListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    }

    class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    }//graphicsPanel

}//class game
```

Answer (score 3):

1. To rotate images, consider using an AffineTransform.
2. The `getRotateInstance(double theta, double anchorx, double anchory)` AffineTransform method could work well here.
3. If you're rotating a wheel, you could use the AffineTransform to create several rotation images, and then store them in an `ArrayList<ImageIcon>` (actually if you code to the interface, a `List<Icon>`).
4. To do the rotations for a period of time that then stops -- use a Swing Timer.
5. If you go the ImageIcon route, you could display your icons in a JLabel and swap them in your Timer's ActionListener by simply calling `myImageLabel.setIcon(myIconList.get(index))` on the JLabel.
6. You'll need to have an int index field to do this that you increment in your Timer, with each call of its `actionPerformed(...)`, i.e., `index++`, and that you mod to the size of the ArrayList in the Timer before using it, `index %= myIconList.size();` so that you don't pass in an index of 20 when trying to get an item from an ArrayList that only has 10 items.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Animated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/) class. It allows you to add an `Icon` to the class and then it will display each `Icon` sequentially at your desired time interval. This class will manage the `Timer` for you.

To aid you in the creation of the Icons to display you can use the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) class to create icons at various degrees of rotation.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class AnimatedIconTest2 extends JPanel
{
    public AnimatedIconTest2()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        String path = "dukeWaveRed.gif";
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        ImageIcon duke = new ImageIcon(imgURL, path);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        final AnimatedIcon icon1 = new AnimatedIcon(label1, 250, 1);
        icon1.setShowFirstIcon( true );
        icon1.addIcon( duke );

        for (int angle = 30; angle < 360; angle += 30)
        {
            icon1.addIcon( new RotatedIcon(duke, angle) );
        }

        label1.setIcon( icon1 );
        add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton start = new JButton( "Start" );
        add(start, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        start.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                icon1.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animated Icon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new AnimatedIconTest2() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```